# How can I regularise this limit?

Tags: limits

I was trying to work out an equation in QFT and I got this limit:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{\frac{x}{\sin(xT)}}$$

It comes from the kernel of an infinite number of harmonic oscillators.

Now obviously this limit doesn't converge in the usual sense as it is both periodic and increasing and has poles. Is there any sense in which we can assign a limit to this function?

For example there are ways of assigning numbers to series that don't converge.

Edit: I guess if you change the limit to $x\rightarrow i\infty$ then this goes to zero.

Comment: what is denoted by $T$?

Comment: it is a constant.